# How can I control isUserInteractionEnabled status of a button remotely in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wish to know how something like remotely altering an app's content or an app's UI Elements would look.

I have already been using remoteConfig to alter certain content (for instance, UILabels) remotely, though the response time is variable and not immediate.

What I wish to know is, how can I use Firebase/Cloud Firestore such that I can remotely change the status of my app. For instance, if I want to disable userInteraction for a particular button remotely, how can I go about that? Or if I need to change an image displayed remotely, what knowledge do I need to do this? RemoteConfig is unable to achieve these 2 particular tasks.

Comment: Yes, you can control some aspects of your apps operation and UI based on external components stored in Firestore. However, this is a very broad question and without understanding the entire use case it would be impossible to provide a 'correct' answer. The items you mentioned could easily be altered by changes in Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as changing an app remotely. The app is in sole charge of itself. If the app gets its data from firestore and there is something about that data that makes the app want to disable a button, it disables its own button.

Comment: You can control a LOT of the apps components 'remotely'. The OP wants to update UILabels, disable user interaction for a button or change an image. If the app is coded to get that information from Firebase (for example) you could control all of those elements. You can also change code the app uses remotely as well - for example Cloud Functions. The answer is correct but there are other options to consider and the question is pretty broad.

Comment: @Jay “If the app is coded to get that information from Firebase (for example) you could control all of those elements.” Yes, that is exactly what I said. The app makes the changes based on the information. The cloud does not magically control the app.

Comment: As I said *The answer is correct* and wanted to highlight that certain parts of the app could be 'magically controlled' (lol) fairly easily, especially the items mentioned by the OP as it would not require changing the base code of the app. Additionally if the app leveraged Cloud Functions (for example) that code *could* be changed remotely. Good answer and deserves an up-vote!